# change form action value based on hidden field values

Tags: javascript, forms

When a user selects either 2 or 3 checkboxes, and submits the form, I am trying to change the value of the form action attribute based on the values from 2 or 3 hidden fields.
The hidden fields with a default value of 0 are given the value of 1 when a checkbox is checked.
However it does not work and I'm unsure where to go from here.

My Form:

```
<form id="f" name="f" method="post" onsubmit="return checkform()" action="scripts/false.php">
RSA:<input type="hidden" id="RSAsel" name="RSAsel" value="0" /> 
RSG:<input type="hidden" id="RSGsel" name="RSGsel" value="0" /> 
RSF:<input type="hidden" id="RSFsel" name="RSFsel" value="0" />
<input name="submit" type="button" class="bodytxt" id="button" onclick="javascript:doSubmit();" value="Enrol in these courses">
</form>

<script>
function doSubmit() {

var RSAsel = parseInt(document.getElementById("RSAsel").value);
var RSGsel = parseInt(document.getElementById("RSGsel").value);
var RSFsel = parseInt(document.getElementById("RSFsel").value);  

var target1 = 'scripts/process-combined-3.php';
var target2 = 'scripts/process-combined-rsa-rsg.php';
var target3 = 'scripts/process-combined-rsa-rsf.php';
var target4 = 'scripts/process-combined-rsg-rsf.php';

var theForm=document.getElementById('f');

if (RSAsel === 1 && RSGsel === 1 && RSFsel === 1) {
theForm.action = target1;
theForm.submit();
return true;
}
else if (RSAsel === 1 && RSGsel === 1) {
theForm.action = target2;
theForm.submit();
return true;
}
else if (RSAsel === 1 && RSFsel === 1) {
theForm.action = target3;
theForm.submit();
return true;
}
else if (RSGsel === 1 && RSFsel === 1) {
theForm.action = target4;
theForm.submit();
return true;
}

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get value of hidden field before trying to use it, like:

```
function doSubmit() {

    var RSAsel = document.getElementById("RSAsel").value;
    var RSGsel = document.getElementById("RSGsel").value;
    var RSFsel = document.getElementById("RSFsel").value;
    //rest of your code
}
```

and there's no `header( "Location: $errorurl" );` in javascript, you are confusing it with PHP

Comment: Actually it should be `var RSAsel = parseInt(document.getElementById("RSAsel").value);
    var RSGsel = parseInt(document.getElementById("RSGsel").value);
    var RSFsel = parseInt(document.getElementById("RSFsel").value);` since the values are extracted as strings by default, and the code uses strict comparison

Comment: Hi - thanks for your help here. I have tried both the suggestions above without success. With the additions of the 2 variations of code above produces a PHP error message. Without it, it processes the page with the action default value of;(scripts/false.php).